# Button size according to button text

Tags: html, css, button

I have 3 buttons, which shall have width according to the width of the button text. This only works with display: inline, but I don't want to have the buttons in a line. How can I list the buttons from top to bottom?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6HHq/2/)

CSS

```
 .wrap{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;

  }

.button{
     display:inline;
    background: white;
    padding: 0.1rem;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
            <div class="button">one</div>
            <div class="button">two</div>
            <div class="button">three</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is by using floats. Remove the display rule and add:

```
clear:left;
float:left;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u6HHq/3/)**

```
.button{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    background: white;
    padding: 0.1rem;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: that is great, but what does it actually?

Comment: This float the button to the left ... The next one clear the float and float itself.

Comment: Floating takes and element and moves it as far left (or right) as possible so that text and inline elements can float around it. This also shrinks the container to fit its contents. By also clearing the float, you force the element below any previously floated elements.

Answer (score 1):

You only need clear and float left, and remove display on .button.

Then your code stay well:

**CSS**

```
.wrap
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  }

.button
{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    background: white;
    padding: 0.1rem;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="button">one</div>
    <div class="button">two</div>
    <div class="button">three</div>
</div>
```

If this is not what you need, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.button:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;   
}
```